# How do I connect my Firebase database to a Google script?

Tags: firebase, google-apps-script

I am trying to put pictures that are on Firebase into a google Drive by using google App script. I've no code, I only tried reading the documentation, but it seems to be deprecated. There seems to be a way to use an Oauth token but I could not find a token on my firebase database.

Answer (score 0):

I go into a lot of detail about using OAuth2 and service accounts with Google Apps Script [in this story on Medium](https://medium.com/geekculture/how-to-use-service-accounts-and-oauth2-in-google-apps-script-99c4bc91dc31?sk=91695899162e741ff54bec4d60b6ea7b).

I suppose you want to use Firebase storage? The approach should be similar:

1. Create a service account
2. Use the [OAuth2 library](https://github.com/googleworkspace/apps-script-oauth2) to generate a Bearer token
3. Use that token with the API call via `UrlFetchApp`

It would help if you shared more details on what you're trying to achieve, but this should set you on the right  track.

Comment: Specifically, I am trying to access pictures stores inside Firebase storage, from a google script. From the script, I then want to put those photos into a google Drive. I then want the script to be called from a different application. What you sent me seems to be useful for Firestore. However, I'm not sure how to find a library that translates for the storage of firebase. Thank you!

Comment: Firebase storage uses Google Cloud Storage under the hood, so [this documentation applies](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/downloading-objects#rest-download-object). If you want to use apps script to do that, read through the second example in the article that talks about BigQuery, that approach will be more relevant for your needs than the Firestore one. Unfortunately, as you haven't actually tried anything yet it seems, that's all I can do for you for now short of writing all the code for you.